# Android: want to fetch data from roomDB when 2 variables changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, rx-kotlin

I wanna fetch data from roomDB when variable changed. When folderName changed and when task changed.
I use `MediatorLiveData`, but it doesn't work.
How can I fix it?

This is a view model class.

```
 val folderName = ViewModelFolder.selectedFolder // MutableLiveData<String>
 val filteredTasks = MediatorLiveData<LiveData<List<Task>>>()
 init {
   filteredTasks.addSource(folderName) { name ->
     filteredTasks.value = getTasksByFolderIsDone(name, false)
   }
}
```

Main activity

```
taskViewModel.filteredTasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { tasks ->
  tasks?.let { taskAdapter.setTasks(tasks as List<Task>) }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the `LiveData` should be wrapped in a separate `MediatorLiveData`?

Comment: @Michiel not sure.. Isn't it ok?